# MATLAB: dbload function

Tags: matlab

I am unable to import data with MATLAB. I need to import 59 CSV files into MATLAB struct. I have two problems:
1. When I am trying to import single CSV:

```
a = struct();
a.Arg = dbload('Argenti.csv', 'userDataFieldList=',1,'commentRow=','quarter', 'nan','.');
a.Arg
```

I get an error that a.Arg is a struct with no fields.

Second, can I import all data contained in 59 CSV files of my working directory rather than doing it 59 times for each country?

Comment: You should mark my answer as accepted because I answered the 2 problems you outlined.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hadn't initialized the `struct`. Why are you using a `struct` though? You will need to know the `struct` field names every time you access it. A better way would be to use a cell array. This might be a peculiarity of `dbload` which I don't know anything about but if not, consider switching to the commented code which uses cell arrays instead. It would be far easier to work with.

```
ext = '.csv';
countries = dir(['*', ext]);
countryFiles = {countries.name};

countriesNames = strrep(countryFiles, ext, '');

% Uncomment if you want n letter abbreviations
% n = 3;
% countriesNames = cellfun(@(s) s(1:min([length(s), n])), countriesNames, 'uni', 0);

% So I would recommend getting rid of all of this
%   Because you will need to eval in a loop everytime you want to access
%   your data
emptyCellArray = cell(size(countriesNames));
stuctConstructingCellArray = vertcat(countriesNames(:)', emptyCellArray(:)');
a = struct(stuctConstructingCellArray{:});

for i = 1:length(countriesNames)
    eval(['a.', countriesNames{i},' = dbload(', countryFiles{i},', ''userDataFieldList='',1,''commentRow='',''quarter'', ''nan'',''.'')']);
end

% and going with the commented code below
%   Because you can use cellfun on it, in the code below I put the country
%   code in the first column and the database in the corresponding rows of
%   the second column.
%
% a = cell(length(countriesNames), 2);
% a(:,1) = countriesNames(:)';
% a(:,2) = cellfun(@(file) dbload(file, 'userDataFieldList=',1,'commentRow=','quarter', 'nan','.'), countryFiles(:)', 'uni', 0);
```

Comment: * `'userDataField='` [ char | *`'.'`* ] - A leading character denoting
  userdata fields for individual time series; if empty, no userdata fields
  will be read in and created.
 
  * `'userDataFieldList='` [ cellstr | numeric | empty ] - List of row
  headers, or vector of row numbers, that will be included as user data in
  each time series.

Comment: This is something that I know nothing about. Please close this question then open a new one with the tags Matlab and dbload then provide a link to the help page of the site for this function.